# How can I replace text with white text to hide it (without hiding the underline) using a Google App script in Google Docs

Tags: google-apps-script, replace, colors, styles, underline

I am a teacher and I would like to have tests with answers built in.  I'd like the be able to hide/unhide (toggle) answers.  If I put {{   }}  around some text, I'd like the script to change the text color to white (hence not visible) or change it to red if it is currently invisible.

Ideally, the text color should not change the underline color - I'd like that to remain black if possible.

Here is what I have tried:

```
function toggleHIDDENtext() {
  var doc  = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument();
  //var regExp= "[A-Za-z0-9\w:.,'’\" \-]+"
  var start="{{"    // this indicates the start of what I want to hide
  var end="}}"      // this indicates the end of what I want to hide
  var regExp= "[*]+"   //regular expression saying 'anything'

  var textToHighlight = start + regExp + end;
  var paras = doc.getParagraphs();
  var textLocation = {};
  
  for (var i=0; i<paras.length; ++i) {
    textLocation = paras[i].findText(textToHighlight);
    if (textLocation != null && textLocation.getStartOffset() != -1) {
      highlightColor = textLocation.getElement().getForegroundColor(textLocation.getStartOffset());
      if(highlightColor=="#ff0000"){   //swapbetween red and white
        hidden="#ffffff"
      }else{
        hidden="#ff0000"
      }
      textLocation.getElement().setForegroundColor(textLocation.getStartOffset(),textLocation.getEndOffsetInclusive(), hidden);
    }
  }
}
```

The line of code

```
    textLocation = paras[i].findText(textToHighlight);
```

does not capture anything and thus nothing works.

Comment: The obfuscation you describe is so easy to circumvent that you may want to look at other options. Note that the `[*]+` pattern will not match "anything" but will only match one or more asterisks `*`. Use something like `\{\{.+?\}\}` or `\{\{[\s\S]+?\}\}` to match text in double curly braces. See [regex quickstart](http://www.regular-expressions.info/quickstart.html).

Comment: About `Ideally, the text color should not change the underline color - I'd like that to remain black if possible.`, in the current stage, I think that this cannot be achieved. Because when the foreground color of text is changed, the underline is also changed to the color. So, about `I'd like the script to change the text color to white (hence not visible) or change it to red if it is currently invisible.`, if the text color is changed to white, the underline is also changed to the same color. From this situation, unfortunately, I think that your goal cannot be achieved. I apologize for this.